# Why setting color has no effect on \hrule?

Tags: pdftex, color

When processing the following example with pdftex:

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\nopagenumbers
\pdfliteral direct {1 0 0 rg}
\line{\leaders\hrule\hfill}
\bye
```

we get a pdf file containing this:

```
stream
1 0 0 rg
q
1 0 0 1 72 710.237 cm
[]0 d 0 J 0.398 w 0 0 m 468 0 l S
Q

endstream
```

As we can see, the color is set in the right place. But why is the rule not red in the pdf document?

BTW, can somebody decrypt the above code which draws the rule? What is the *current transformation* that is set and restored with `q` and `Q`? And what is *current transformation* anyway? And what is the function of the transformation matrix set here with "cm"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDF knows a color for stroking and for filling. The example sets the fill color, but the line is stroked. Using the stroke color operator (`RG`) instead of the fill color operator (`rg`) fixes this example:

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\nopagenumbers
\pdfliteral direct {1 0 0 RG}
\line{\leaders\hrule\hfill}
\bye
```

> [image: Result with stroke color and red line]

However, it depends on the line thickness, which kind of operation pdfTeX chooses for the rule. For example, a large square is filled and needs the fill color operator:

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\nopagenumbers
\pdfliteral direct {1 0 0 rg}
\line{\vrule width 10mm height 10mm}
\bye
```

> [image: Result red square with fill color operator]

For this reasons, LaTeX sets *both* colors operators to cover both cases:

```
1 0 0 rg 1 0 0 RG
```

### "Decryption" of the stream data in the question:

```
stream
1 0 0 rg                % set red as *fill* color in model RGB
q                       % save
  1 0 0 1 72 710.237 cm % move origin to (72 bp, 710.237 bp)
  []0 d                 % set dash pattern (empty dash pattern)
  0 J                   % set line join type (solid)
  0.398 w               % set line width to 0.398 bp = 0.4 pt
  0 0 m                 % move to (0 bp, 0 bp)
  468 0 l               % line to (468 bp, 0 bp)
  S                     % stroke
Q                       % restore

endstream
```